# How can I have my .NET 6 project automatically generate classes for ALL XSD files using globbing?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xsd, csproj

I have a .NET Core 6.0 project, which contains *.xsd files in a folder named '*Schemas*'. Currently, I am using the XSD tool provided by Microsoft to generate C# classes/files manually. Is there a way to use globbing within my project file to automatically execute the tool for all *.xsd files in the '*Schemas*' folder?

Comment: Where did those schemas come from? If they came from a WSDL file you can generate a client with operations and all DTOs by pointing Visual Studio or the `svcutil` tool to the WSDL file.

Comment: Unless these schemas update regularly, it's probably best to generate the classes once using XSD.EXE, and then you have the code to build against, rather than it being part of the build itself.

Comment: Try from cmd.exe (or put into a bat file) : for %f in (*.xsd) do xsd.exe /l:cs /c